# Unity3D is unable to find jar system path after importing google play services library

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services

Iam trying to upload a simple Unity3D test app on my Google Play Games Console. The only purpose of this is to get familiarized with the workings of this as I have just opened up my account and Iam a first timer on the subject.

I have started out with a great tutorial on implementing Google Play Services Library I found on YT. The test app was working okay except for the end part where I had problems with the built. Nevertheless I decided to redo the test app from the begining for better understanding and memorization of the procces and maybe figuring out why the build was not working as it should have been.

Before redoing everyting I upgraded Unity to 5.4.1f1. (from 5.3.3f1)

Now after I import the Google Play Services Library to the project and try to setup the Google Play Games > Setup > Android Setup, Unity is suddenly unable to find jar system path.

When I press play button I get the below error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTMqn.png)

I went through the readme file, made sure everything was done as listed ([source](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)), read through dozens of questions/answers here and on Unity Community, and I still cannot find a soultion for my problem. I made sure that the paths were correct, checked other projects and they are still working fine. So the problem starts with importation of the GPSL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: we had the same problem, solved after updating android sdk

Comment: Have you solved it? I have the same problem.

Comment: No, I have not. I have been wasting time with this  for days. Uninstalled Android Studio and reinstalled it afresh, didn't change a thing.

Any help still appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved the problem. I was not paying enough attention to the redame file on Git.

I had a set JDK variable in Users variables but instead in needed to add also  JAVA_HOME variable.

[Solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2PbK.png)

To set the variable you need to go to Computer/Properties/Advanced system settings/Enviroment variables and set it there.

Do not forget to also add a PATH in the Systems variables.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much. Dont get why I have to set that by hand myself thou. Is that supposed to be a thing google play services plugin do by himself? That would explain, since I got the project by cloning a git repo.

Comment: And reboot your computer after setting the variables.